# The timing of using conditional statements in ejs

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ejs

I am confusing when dealing with the logic in Javascript and the ejs template. I could write all the logic inside the conditional statements such as for loop inside the template with syntax `<% %>` around the statement. It is able, for sure to write the same logic inside the Javascript file. In Javascript, for example:

```
if (posts.length == 0) {
   //do something
}
```

In ejs:

```
<% if (posts.length == 0) { %>
   //do something
<% } %>
```

It's the same functionality, but in JS, it's easier to debug and auto-complete syntax; in the ejs, it's easier to put HTML element such as anchor tag to wrap the hyperlink. Therefore, is there any principle I can follow to write the conditional statements in which file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the files separated and pass the javascript code in a server.
Generally, it's best practice to keep your code separated in easy readable files for debugging and general project management.

Example: - (somethingfun.js)

```
let variable
    if(posts.length == 0) {
        // do something fun
        // store the value in a variable
        something(fun) = variable
    }
// Export your variable off the javascript file
module.export = variable
```

And then you can simply, in your server application, import the javascript file.

Your ejs template will automatically understand the value of your *variable*. Thus helping you keep the code clean and neat.

**I generally create a file for all the utilities, one for all the API services and one for all the UI elements.**

Commenting also helps a TON!!!!

Comment: Thank you for sharing what usually you do in practice. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

After a week, I discover the technology that is exactly for dealing with this issue. It's the popular React.js package that renders HTML elements and deals with the entire logic inside the js file.